# PL/SQL create trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Create a trigger called biufer_customer that starts before insert or update of the column passwd in the customer table. The trigger shall verify that the password is exactly six characters long, no more, no less. Unless this requirement is fulfilled, the trigger shall stop the transaction and confirm that this error occurred.

```
create or replace trigger biufer_customer
before insert or update 
of passwd
on customer
for each row
when (new.passwd <> 6)
begin
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Wrong password!');
end;
/
```

Comment: What is your actual question? We're not just going to do your assignment for you. What is that code? Did you try running it? Did it cause an error? What was that?

Comment: What about special characters, i.e. non-ASCII characters? Many times you are advised to use special characters for your password. You can count differently, see [LENGTH](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions100.htm#SQLRF00658)

Comment: I had missed the length function, now the code works : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `LENGTH` function

```
...
when(length(new.passwd) <> 6) 
...
```

Comment: I had missed the length function. Thanks a lot : )